# facebook object returns accessToken as null

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-access-token

i am developing a fecebook application using php.i created a app and  approved the permissions then i run  the below code but it returns access-token as null and user as 0,what will be the problem

```
require_once("facebook.php");
$config = array();
$config['appId'] = '****';
$config['secret'] = '*****';
$config['cookie'] = true;
$config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional
$facebook = new Facebook($config);
var_dump($facebook);
$user = $facebook->getUser();
echo "user=".$user;
```

the output is given

```
object(Facebook)#1 (9) {
["sharedSessionID":protected]=>NULL
["appId":protected]=> string(15) "63270097007****"
["appSecret":protected]=>string(32) "****************"
["user":protected]=>NULL
["signedRequest":protected]=>NULL
["state":protected]=> string(32) "****************"
["accessToken":protected]=>NULL
["fileUploadSupport":protected]=>  bool(false)
["trustForwarded":protected]=>bool(false)
}
user=0
```

Comment: You must use getAccessToken() to catch token? Second thing - when getUser() returns null you must redirect user to FB auth page which  is generated with getLoginUrl from yout FB PHP api.

Answer (score 0):

You can get more info over here..

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/publishing-with-app-token/

```
// Modify you code in this way.

require_once("facebook.php");
$config = array();
$config['appId'] = '****';
$config['secret'] = '*****';
$config['cookie'] = true;
$config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional
$facebook = new Facebook($config);
var_dump($facebook);
$user = $facebook->getUser();

//Get Access Token URL
$access_token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=".$config['appId']."&client_secret=".$config['secret']."&grant_type=client_credentials";

//Get Access Token
$access_token = file_get_contents($access_token_url);
echo $access_token;
```

Now, you should get Acess token..

Comment: 1st this will return App token but it wont return user token and 2nd why you keep the Facebook () init and separate you make file_get_contest request?

Comment: Hmm.. He didn't specify the type of token he requested. He added the output just now. And I've just added 2 lines below to get App access token.